# Extracting data from Firebase data snapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from a DataSnapshot from firebase. I can see the DataSnapShot in logs but I am getting an error when assigning it to a variable. See below for more details

In logcat:

> D/loggxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: DataSnapshot { key = latitude, value = -20.0688881 }
> D/loggxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: DataSnapshot { key = longitude, value = 57.5226424 }

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
        Log.d("loggxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",dataSnapshot.toString());
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, dataSnapshot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Nodata", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

My Firebase Realtime database looks like this:

```
"location": {
  "HarryMaguire": {
    "latitude": "-20.0688881",
    "longitude": "57.5226424"
  },
  "RoseGilbert": {
    "latitude": "20.3484",
    "longitude": "57.5522"
  },
```

Comment: 1) "I am getting an error" Please edit your question to show the exact error you get. 2) "I can see the DataSnapShot in logs" Please edit your question to show exactly what you see in the logs. 3) Please edit your question to show how you actually read the data, and include the JSON from that location in your database (in text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, I just updated the questions

Comment: Thanks for that. This covers the #2 and the second half of #3. Please edit your question to also include: 1) the exact error message and stack trace you get, 2) the code that reads the data, including the call to `addChildEventListener` and how the `DatabaseReference` you call that on is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to pull data from firebase database. I think you are having a problem with data extraction. And this kotlin

```
 fun getDataFromFirestore() {
    val userID = sharedPreferences.getString("Firma_Firebase_ID", "")
    if (userID != "") {
        val DB = Firebase.firestore
        DB.collection("Database").document(userID.toString()).addSnapshotListener{ snapshot, error ->
        val document = snapshot?.data
        runBlocking {
            launch {
                if (snapshot != null && document != null) {
                    val name = document.get("name") as? String
                    if (name != null) {
                        Name = name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Notify
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have it in java?

Comment: of course, but the syntax may be different, for example, I don't know if run block exists in java, I just wrote kotlin. It has an equivalent. detail in this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?hl=en&authuser=0#java_4

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attaching a `ChildEventListener` to the `location/HarryMaguire` path in your database. When you do that, `onChildAdded` gets trigger with each child property of `location/HarryMaguire`, which is why you see logs for `latitude` and `longitude`.

*Will update more, once the question provides the necessary information.*

Comment: But how do I store the latitude and longitude in a variable? I am trying:  Float lat = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Float.class);              But it return me a null value

Comment: Did the explanation I gave in my answer make sense? Did you change your code based on that? If so, add an update to tyour question to show that updated code. That's also a good moment to ask the additional information I asked for in my comments yesterday.